# Push Email to Unresolved Items(Emails)

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, emailmessage

I have an issue with pushing EmailMessage to Unresolved Items(Emails) **in Apex**.

I use custom **Email Service**(not My Email to Salesforce) and have my custom logic for incoming email in Apex class.

What I need is, for specific case scenario(**When the email subject is empty**) push the email to **Unresolved Items(Emails)**.

I have spent a lot of time to find some workaround for pushing Email to **Unresolved Items**, but did not find anything.

If there any possibilities in Salesforce to make this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well emailMessage obj requires ParentId. 

In my scenario I do not have any CaseId, so I cannot create any Email obj.

I guess the proper solution is: 

- Create one Case which will include all **Unresolved** emails.

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.